# Google Maps API

Tags: twitter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am building a twitter, google maps mash-up.
I am trying add user's twitter profile picture to the map as a custom marker,

I know how to add custom markers from images but was wondering if there was any easy way of adding a different image for every marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can make google maps use a kml file which can be dynamically generated based on current twitter pics. A kml file is a basically an xml file that contains geo-data.

The following link will provide you with examples, look at Marker Icons. There is also sample kml format for what your placemark mark up should look like. It consists of the coordinates of the marker and the picture you want to use.

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/kml.htm